# Issue on retrieving Evernote business note attachments by using Evernote ios sdk

Tags: ios, evernote

I integrated the latest evernote ios sdk in my ios app. When i try to list/retrieve the note attachments from my business notebook (either shared or personal). The call back from evernote sdk giving the same note attachment more than once. Since the return array list has same note attachment more than once. Any idea why?.

> Note: this issue happening in both shared business notebook and
>   personal business note book.

Any help that might be appreciated.

Here is my code:

**Caller:**

```
[SEEvernoteHelper getAttachmentsFoeNoteBook:notebook forSeatchString:@"resource:application/*" onCompletion:^(NSArray *list, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            block (nil, error);
        } else {
            //success
        }
}
```

note book attachment retriever:

```
+ (void)getAttachmentsFoeNoteBook:(ENNotebook *)notebook forSeatchString:(NSString *)searchString onCompletion:(ZArrayResultBlock)block {

    [[ENSession sharedSession] findNotesWithSearch:[ENNoteSearch noteSearchWithSearchString:searchString]
                                        inNotebook:notebook
                                           orScope:nil
                                         sortOrder:ENSessionSortOrderRelevance
                                        maxResults:0
                                        completion:^(NSArray *findNotesResults, NSError *findNotesError) {
                                            if (findNotesError) {
                                                if (block) {
                                                    block(nil, findNotesError);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                block(findNotesResults, nil);
                                            }
                                        }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the lead developer for the evernote ios sdk.

Can you file a bug on https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/issues and let's resolve it there?

Thanks

Comment: i already filed an issue over there. Please check this link for more info: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/issues/35

Comment: giftederic, please let me know when this issue will be fix.